# Hrushovski's Construction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lo.logic, model-theory, combinatorial-geometry, infinite-combinatorics

Zilber expressed a conjecture for $\aleph_{1}$- categorical theories (In the 80s).

**Zilber's Conjecture:** The geometry of any $\aleph_{1}$- categorical structure is one of the following:

**(a)** Trivial (No structure)

**(b)** Linear (Locally modular): Vector Spaces.

**(c)** Non-Linear (Non Locally modular): Algebraically Closed Fields(ACF).

In other words Zilber conjectured that any non-locally modular strongly
minimal set interprets an ACF.

Hrushovski construct a new class of $\aleph_{1}$- categorical structures, disproving Zilber's conjecture.(A New Strongly Minimal Set - Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 1993 ).

Hrushovski generalized the Frasse's method to construct his counter example.
Hrushovski construct an $\omega$- saturated strongly minimal set whose geometry is *flat*.

**Definition:** A combinatorial geometry J is *flat* if whenever $E_{i}(i\in I)$ are finite number of finite-dimensional closed subset of J, s ranges over the subsets of I, then $\sum_{s}(-1)^{card(s)}\leq0$.

Hrushovski proved the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let D be a saturated strongly minimal set whose geometry is flat. Then D does not interpret an infinite group. So D does not interpret an ACF.

**Question:** Can we use Hrushovski's method to find a saturated strongly minimal set whose geometry is not flat ?